# make FEOF return true sooner to avoid explode() "Undefined offset" error (PHP)

Tags: php, explode, feof

I have this simple program that print the content of a file

```
<?php

$fp=fopen("../resources/client.txt","r"); 
$trouve=0;
$cnt=0;
while(!feof($fp)){
    $i=0;
    $cnt++;
    echo "<br>";
    $ligne=fgets($fp);
    $row=explode("|",$ligne);
    while($i<=2){
        echo $row[$i]."|";
        $i++;}
    
}

fclose($fp); ?>
```

It does the job but after displaying i get also these errors:[image]

Is there a simpe solution for this problem?
Thank you all  in advance.

Comment: An empty line in your file? Btw `feof` is false after EOF was reached, ie fgets might get a blank input...

Comment: What is the content of the file ?

Comment: My guess? `while(!feof($fp))` That will not break the loop until *after* you already tried to read beyond the end of the file (and [`fgets`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) returns `false`). Instead use `while ($ligne=fgets($fp))`

Comment: sorry for taking time to respond i was in school when I posted this question

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad yes actually there is one, i removed it and it did work thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that one worked even if there is an empty line ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

On en empty line you have no `$row[1]` neither nor `$row[2]`

```php
<?php

$fp=fopen("../resources/client.txt","r"); 
$trouve=0;
$cnt=0;
while(!feof($fp)){
    $i=0;
    $cnt++;
    echo "<br>";
    $ligne=fgets($fp);
    $row=explode("|",$ligne);
    if (isset($row[$i])) {
        while($i<=2){
            echo $row[$i]."|";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    
}

fclose($fp); ?>
```